# Reversing a properties file content

Tags: java, ant, properties-file

I've a properties file (say exmp.properties) which is something like this

```
1. k5=500
2. k4=400
3. k3=300
4. k2=200
5. k1=100
```

I need to reverse the content of this file like

```
1. k1=100
2. k2=200
3. k3=300
4. k4=400
5. k5=500
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using ANT task or Java code?

Comment: Apart from the answers why you want to reverse the contents of the properties file? As you can fetch any property you want where order do not matters?

Comment: Why? Order is immaterial in a properties file. It's a hash map. There is no sequential access in file order.

Comment: Sounds like a homework exercise to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with [loadresource](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) and nested [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).
To make it work correctly your propertyfile needs a linefeed after last property, means :

```
k5=500
k4=400
k3=300
k2=200
k1=100
-- empty line --
```

snippet :

```
<project>
 <loadfile property="unsorted" srcfile="foobar.properties"/>
 <echo>unsorted: ${line.separator}${unsorted}</echo>

 <loadresource property="sorted">
  <string value="${unsorted}" />
   <filterchain>
    <sortfilter />
   </filterchain>
 </loadresource>
 <echo>sorted: ${line.separator}${sorted}</echo>
 <!-- write file -->
 <echo file="foobar_sorted.properties">${sorted}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] unsorted:
[echo] k5=500   
[echo] k4=400   
[echo] k3=300   
[echo] k2=200   
[echo] k1=100   
[echo] sorted:  
[echo] k1=100   
[echo] k2=200   
[echo] k3=300   
[echo] k4=400   
[echo] k5=500
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```java
String input = "in.txt";
String output = "out.txt";

try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output)) {
    //read all lines
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(input), Charset.defaultCharset());

    //clear contents of the output file
    fw.write("");
    //write all lines in reverse order
    for (int i = lines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        fw.append(lines.get(i) + System.lineSeparator());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

This reads all lines of the file and then writes them in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just a text file. "[Read in the file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)" "[reverse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137755/how-do-i-reverse-an-int-array-in-java)" and "[write to the file again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054644/java-io-writing-into-a-text-file-line-by-line)".