# Fastest way to write/read huge stream data sample by sample in text/csv file Java

Tags: java, file, stream

I have streams which contains above 1 to 17 milion records. For every record I doing some processing and I want save result which is BigDecimal value.

- What would be the fastest way to save those data? I don't want keep it all in memory and save on end. I want save every result when record processing is done.
- What would be the most efficient structure on disk? .txt/.csv file? Futher I want load data for charts. For exemple from result 2000 to 10000. What data structure or read data solution provide fastest work?

Comment: I would try something simple first, like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062113/fastest-way-to-write-huge-data-in-text-file-java - basically BufferedWriter / FileWriter. Modern systems are blazingly fast and 17M BigDecimals is not that much data.

Comment: For saving tons of BigDecimal to disk: consider ObjectOutputStream. Conversion to and from String can be avoided.