# Writing 100,000 lines in a csv in fastest way possible

Tags: java, csv, opencsv, fast-csv

I m trying to create a zip of 100 csv. 
I need to write 100,000 lines in a single csv in fastest way possible. 
I am using openCSV, ZipEntry method to write to csv.

Some Code used:

```
ZipEntry zipentry = new ZipEntry(filename);
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
CSVWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos));
writer.writeNext(entries); //entries is single line of csv
```

Currently its taking 1.5 secs to write a single csv and overall its taking around 120-140secs to create complete zip.

I have debugged the code, and observed that the other computations in the code is not taking time, but the write operation does takes time.

I have tried creating list of 100,000 lines and then writing one one file at a time instead if direct streaming. But still it takes same time.

Please suggest fastest method which takes less time. ;-(

Comment: A hard disc is inherently a slow device.  If you really need speedy IO consider a solid state drive (and yes, I mean in a production system).

Comment: But i want to do it from java perspective. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Your can run each write asynchronously to speed up the process. Try ten at a time and you should be done in 15 seconds.

Comment: I can't do async, since the data which is getting write is computated first and they r dependent on previous data.

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedOutputStream` improves IO performance by a large margin:

see [Javadoc: BufferedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html)

> By setting up such an output stream, an application can write bytes to the underlying output stream without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for each byte written.

```
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(zos, 1<<16);
CSVWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out);
```

Comment: It didn't change anything...need to try something else. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try using less aggressive compression level for your ZipOutputStream such as 3:

> public void setLevel(int level)

Comment: Dunno if this will work but it seems a cogent idea.