# Fastest way to write file (approx 5GB) in Java

Tags: java, file, file-writing

I am trying to write into file huge file of approximately 5GB but not able to write data in a buffer, it still writes out one line at a time.

I have already tried using:

```
PrintWriter ps = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(originalPath), (8192 * 6)), false);
```

I am using JDK 11.
Does anyone know fastest way to write into a text file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062113/fastest-way-to-write-huge-data-in-text-file-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to write huge data in text file Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062113/fastest-way-to-write-huge-data-in-text-file-java)